# replacing default sqlite with couchdb database for django test optimization

Tags: django, sqlite, unit-testing, couchdb, django-testing

[Django allows auto database routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing). It is possible to have different databases for test and production. The default for test is sqlite3. Will migrating from `sqlite3` to `couchdb` will have any significant time improvement for unittests which take more than 10 mins. to run?

What other if any test db optimization can be done?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information here. Are you switching solely to improve your test performance? Your tests take 10 minutes to run: have you looked into optimizing the tests' performance? I'd think switching from SQL to a NoSQL db would require much rework: is that the case here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that you could successful replace SQLite with CouchDB and save all his features unless your SQLite usage is very basic. Knowing how much sqlite allows to do, that couldn't be so easy.

CouchDB could speedup your tests if only you're using quite trivial SQL queries or you have complex computations on query results. Since CouchDB views stores ready-to-use results with update-on-demand request semantic this could save you some CPU time.

However, have you tried to use [:memory:](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) storage? Or work with test db on tmpfs? Also note, that with CouchDB your tests may suffer from network latency - HTTP requests are not so cheap as function calls through driver (sqlite is just database driver, not complete RDBMS).

P.S. Note, that I'm not talking from position of Django ORM or others since normally they couldn't provide good effectiveness as native libraries. For example, SQLite allows custom `SELECT` queries, while `views` are rarely used while CouchDB works better with predefined `views` rather than custom queries (`temporary views`).

Comment: If you use sqlite3 in tests testing database is created in memory out of box in Django.

Comment: @jasiz really? I've always thought that configuration depended behavior since, probably, you'd like to look at db state after all test runs or, if some of them fails, to overview db state or use pregenerated db for tests target etc. Unless testing seems to be really painful.

Comment: Yeah, really ;) And even other databases are destroyed after tests https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#the-test-database

Comment: OMG, you right...However, Google helps to found a lot of workarounds of this behavior, but it's sad that there is no customization out of box. Thanks for note, sorry for offtopic(:

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use completely different settings for developing/testing instead of routers.

If the database is main reason why test run so long it is often because of using fixtures in tests, which are loaded before every test - using https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy or similar solution can be very helpful.